# Implicit Conversion of 'nsinteger' (aka 'long') to 'nsstring *' is Disallowed with Arc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, string-comparison

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender   {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mnuSelected"])
{
    ViewController *v = segue.destinationViewController;

    if(self.searchDisplayController.active) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    v.str = [self.result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSIndexPath *rowSelected = nil;
        rowSelected = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        v.UserSelected = rowSelected.row; //error in this line 

}
    else {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    v.str = [self.monthName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSIndexPath *rowSelected = nil;
        rowSelected = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        v.UserSelected = rowSelected.row;

 }
    return; }
 }
```

I have error in this line : v.UserSelected = rowSelected.row; 
The error is : Implicit conversion of 'nsinteger' (aka 'long') to 'nsstring *' is disallowed with arc

Comment: try v.UserSelected = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%d", rowSelected.row];

Comment: How is declared `UserSelected` in `ViewController`? As `NSString` supposedly. Why a `NSString` ? Why not a `NSInteger`?

Comment: UserSelected is a? int, long, string?? please specify it in your question

Comment: UserSelected is a string

Comment: i want send data to show in next page pass  v.UserSelected.  Example UIImage *imgTwitter = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"];    UserSelected isEqual:@"this is Twitter"])  img.image = imgTwitter;

Comment: It should be a number; the same type as `NSIndexPath.row`.

Comment: ok thank you for all comment. I can do it :D

Answer (score 6):

Try using below code:

```
v.UserSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long) rowSelected.row];
```

**NOTE:** If you try to set the value as :

`v.UserSelected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowSelected.row];`

You will get compiler warning :

> Values of type NSInteger should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead

You get this warning if you compile on OS X (64-bit), because on that platform NSInteger is defined as long and is a 64-bit integer. The %d format, on the other hand, is for int, which is 32-bit. So the format and the actual parameter do not match in size.

Since NSInteger is 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the platform, the compiler recommends to add a cast to long generally.